# An alternative web framework (instead of JSF) to use with CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets, web-frameworks, cdi

Is there other Java Web frameworks other than JSF which work well with CDI? "Work well" could be simply to have a template system which can access `@Named` beans.

Rationale: I do not like the event-driven nature of JSF a lot, so my preferred answer would be an action-based web framework. A framework which also supports `@ConversationScoped` contexts and facelets would be perfect but any alternative (even an event-driven one) is an acceptable answer, the least for kill my curiosity :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a ready-to-use integration with Wicket - [see here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.1-Final/en-US/html/viewlayers.html). Apart from that you can use any framework by providing some interceptor/filter that reaches into the CDI bean manager and looks up bean by name (perhaps via a custom `ELResolver`)